# need help in aggregate select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a problem with selecting some values from my DB. DB is in design stages so i can redesign it a bit of needed.

You can see the [Diagram on this image](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/6172/99842299.png)

Basically what i want to select is

```
select 
c.campaignID,
ct.campaignTypeName,
c.campaignName,
c.campaignDailyBudget,
c.campaignTotalBudget,
c.campaignCPC,
c.date,
cs.campaignStatusName
***impressions,
***clicks,
***cast(campaignTotalBudget-(clicks*campaignCPC) as decimal(18,1)) as remainingFunds 
from Campaigns as c
left join CampaignTypes as ct on c.campaignTypeID=ct.campaignTypeID
left join CampaignStatuses as cs on c.campaignStatusID=cs.campaignStatusID
left join CampaignVariants as cv on c.campaignID=cv.campaignID
left join CampaignVariants2Visitors as c2v on cv.campaignVariantID=c2v.campaignVariantID
left join Visitors as v on c2v.visitorID=v.visitorID
.....
order by c.campaignID desc
```

Problem is that Visitors table has column named isClick so i don't know the way to separate what is impression with isClick=false and what is click isClick=true so i can show nice form with all the stuff about campaign and visitors...

I don't think to split Visitors to two tables like Impressions and Click is a good idea because again i would need to have Visitors with two more tables

thanks

Comment: could you clarify your question a bit more? You are referring to **impression** like it is an object. What is it? Are you trying to get a count of isClick=false vs isClick=true?

Comment: yep, isClick=0 is an impression and isClick=1 is a click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what "impressions" are in your diagram. However, if you are wondering how to count clicks per campaign, you can do something like:

```
Select ...
From Campaigns As c
    ...
    Left Join (
                Select V1.VisitorId
                    , CV2V1.CompaignVariantID
                    , Sum( Case When V1.IsClick = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As ClickCount
                    , Count(*) TotalVisitorCount
                From Visitors As V1
                    Join CompaignVariant2Visitors As CV2V1
                        On CV2V1.VisitorId = V1.VisitorID
                Group By V1.VisitorId, CV2V1.CompaignVariantID
                ) As VisitTotals
        On VisitTotals.VisitorId= C2V.VisitorId
            And VisitTotals.CampaignVariantID = C2V.CampaignVariantID
...
Order By c.campaignID desc
```

Comment: isClick=0 is an impression and isClick=1 is a click, i guess you did it right.

Comment: @eugeneK - It should be noted that TotalVisitorCount will effectively be IsClick = 0 or IsClick = 1. If you wanted to know the number of instances of IsClick =0, then you would want to add another column into the VisitTotals derived table like ClickCount except for IsClick = 0.

Comment: thanks. Actually it does the job as isClick=1 will be summed in total number of clicks while impressions would be row count-(isClick=1)

thanks